# How to start creating an Ipad application? Migrate from Iphone to Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I successfully created an Iphone application...Now I want to create the equivalent Ipad application with bigger resolution but the same functionality.. How to start ?
Should I create a separate Application for the Ipad or can I extend the Iphone one to support Ipad big screens ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go to your App Summary and set Devices to **Universal**.

Then you can run the app in both clients. Just make sure the UI scales with the different resolutions, and you will be fine.

Also, this will ensure that people who bought it for one device don't need to buy it for a second device. Plus you can keep rating, updates and comments syncronized.

Comment: ok ..thank you..and how to scale the UI ? I wanna to change the background for example.

Comment: I do my UI scaling by script. Under ViewDidAppear i just make sure that the width or height of the elements (or what is required) have the same or relatively same with and height as the screen. You can always get the top layer resolution throgh **this.view.window**

Comment: Have 2 xibs.. one for iPhone and one for ipad. Runtime you can determine which device the app is running on, and instantiate the viewcontroller with the appropriate view controller

Comment: yes :] I run my views in pure script without xibs, but that is a way to go at it too.